# GCP Storage: url encoded Object Path added to Object Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have the following folder structure in my bucket:

Structure: Bucket-Name/YEAR/Folder/Objects
Example Path: mybucket/2018/myEXEs/file.exe

Issue: When I try to download an object (file.exe) from example path above by clicking on the EXE, the filename that appears in the download dialog box looks like this:

"2018%2FmyEXEs%2Ffile.exe"

You have to strip the URL encoded path every time and this is an inconvenience if you do not want to make the URL public.

Observation:

- It appears the storage browser adds bucket path to the filename and that gets encoded to replace '/'.
- This does not happen when you download the object using public URL.

Question: 
Is there a way to strip the URL encoded path from filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [feature request](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35961645) in the public tracker for this. As mentioned in the same link, there is a workaround by setting the filename in the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) metadata of the files. To do it, go to `Cloud Storage`, edit metadata of a file and, in `Content-Disposition` field, add:

```
attachment; filename="filename"
```

The the only inconvenient with this workaround is that you have to set filenames in all the download files's metadatas.

Comment: Thanks Enle for pointing this out. I ended up writing a small script that bulk updates the meta-data.